# Datalist change row color using itemdatabound event problem

Tags: .net, datalist, web-controls, itemdatabound

I am trying to change the row color of a DataList Control...

```
        <asp:DataList ID="dlTrades" Width="100%" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
            RepeatColumns="6" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="objTrds" 
            OnItemDataBound="dlTrades_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
             <table>
                   <tr>
                    <td>
                      <b>
                      <%# DataBinder.Eval((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem, "Status") %>
                      </b>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                 </table>
                 <table>
                   <tr>
                      <td><%# DataBinder.Eval((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem, "Hold") %>
                      </td>
                   </tr> 
                 </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

with the following itemdatabound event:

```
protected void dlTrades_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        System.Data.DataRowView drv = (System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem);

        string hld = (string)drv.Row["Hold"].ToString();

        if (hld == "Trade")
        {
            e.Item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
            e.Item.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            e.Item.Font.Bold = true;
        }

        if (hld == "Hold")
        {
            e.Item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            e.Item.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            e.Item.Font.Bold = true;
        }

        System.Data.DataRowView drv2 = (System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem);

        string stat = (string)drv2.Row["Status"].ToString();

        if (stat == "Open")
        {
            e.Item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
            e.Item.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            e.Item.Font.Bold = true;
        }
        if (stat == "Filled")
        {
            e.Item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold;
            e.Item.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            e.Item.Font.Bold = true;
        }

        if (stat == "Closed")
        {
            e.Item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.IndianRed;
            e.Item.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            e.Item.Font.Bold = true;
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that whatever is the last set of background colors does both rows.. how can I separate the rows so that one row is 'Status' color and one  row is 'Hold' Color??

I tried using div tags as a prev post mentioned but divID.Attributes.Add(set style: color) did not compile...

Thanks,

Comment: I think I am going to use a Label control instead and use the previous / standard way of doing this instead of going for the row using some weird sort of div tag reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Label Control and expanding it 100% of column width works well for this.